# FFmpeg add rotation to a video generated from an image

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am new to FFmpeg and I don't know how to add `rotate="90"` to my command. I tried to add it in different places and I get `Unable to find suitable output format for 'rotate=90' rotate=90: Invalid argument`.

I want to append an intro video to a series of other videos taken with an android camera and concatenate them together. The concatenation works fine except the rotation should be in portrait mode and not landscape.

This is my command:

```
const ffmpegCommand = `-hide_banner -loglevel error -loop 1 -i ${imageUri} -f lavfi -i anullsrc=cl=mono:r=48000 -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -level:v 4.0 -video_track_timescale 90k -t ${duration} -pix_fmt yuv420p -r ${resolution[0]/resolution[1]} ${outputUri}`;
```

Comment: your  problem is to capture video in a portrait and displays it on a landscape screen right..?

Comment: @BADSHAH no, I want to avoid re-encoding. I just want to add to this command the rotation attribute. My videos taken with the android camera are in portrait mode and FFmpeg concat makes them landscape because my generated intro video, is the first video in the array and its in landscape. I just want this one to make it portrait so the FFmpeg concat function doesn't rotate the rest of the videos.

Comment: exactly I taking about check video rotation is 90 degrees that video degree change using this command *ffmpeg -y, -i, videoPath, -s, width x height, -preset, veryfast, OutputPath;* after this output path will add your ArrayList then main command problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. I am not sure if its the right solution but for me it does what I need.

```
const ffmpegCommand = `-i ${firstRecordedVideURL} -i ${generatedImageVideoURL} -map 1 -c copy \ -map_metadata 0 \ -map_metadata:s:v 0:s:v \ -map_metadata:s:a 0:s:a \ ${output}`;
```

I take the first video recorded via the android camera and copy the metadata to the video that I just generated from an image file. This way the generated video will have a matching metadata and the concatenation will work as expected.